Kinematics and dynamics of a ballistic pendulum
In which Physics textbooks can one find comprehensive content on the kinematics and dynamics of a ballistic pendulum both in the approximation of the mass and a distributed mass with uniform density?

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but there is some discussion of the compound pendulum in Schaum's Theoretical Mechanics:  https://archive.org/details/schaumsoutlineof0000spie_c9t5/page/228/mode/2up
From page 228:
"Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a rigid body which is free to oscillate in a vertical plane about a fixed horizontal axis through $O$ under the influence of gravity."
The period of vibration is
$$
P=2\pi \sqrt{I_{0}/Mga}
$$
where $I_{0}$ is the moment of inertia, $M$ is the mass, $a$ is the distance from $O$ to the center of mass.
There are some additional derivations and examples on or near that section which may be useful.

Thank you very much.
